# Issue with saving Google API key restrictions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-api-key-restrictions

I am currently having some troubles with saving Google API key restrictions. This is how I have configured in the Credentials Manager.

**Application restrictions**

- Websites (*.azurestaticapps.net)

**API restrictions**

- Geocoding API
- Geolocation API
- Maps JavaScript API
- Places API

When I tried to save, I kept getting "Save failed" error, saying "The attempted action failed, please try again.", along with some tracking number.

I was a bit suspicious about the website URL that I put there, so I tried a different one to see if it'd make any difference, but it still failed with the same error.

I also had a look at this Google's official [help doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?_ga=2.218857689.-1183742504.1677228047#securing_an_api_key). I don't think I missed anything obvious though.

Comment: I reported a bug to the team a month ago related to restrictions with apis not working properly.  They logged it internally I haven't heard anymore about it.

Comment: Did you try with the subdomain? `azurestaticapps.net`

Comment: You should file a Technical Support case so that they can take a look at your project itself. Here's a link that might help you get there: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo managed to find the workaround. see my post below.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yep did that already, and it wasn't the subdomain apparently.

Comment: @Yrll thanks, I am considering raising a support ticket to them.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it another crack earlier today, and luckily found the workaround for it at least.

> To save the API key restrictions successfully, you will have to make
> sure that you only have a single sign-in session in Google Cloud Console. If you have multiple
> ones, you will need to sign them out first, and then sign back in with the
> correct account.

In my case, what happened was that my browser already had another sign-in session previously. It's not that obvious to check whether or not you are signed in multiple sessions in the Google Cloud Console so I totally missed that.

Not too sure if this workaround would 100% work for others, but at least it did the trick for me. Hopefully something useful to know.